# Errors install nodejs Termux

Tags: javascript, node.js, termux

CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "node": cannot locate symbol "__emutls_get_address" referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/node"...
My Enslish isn't good, how can i fix this bug?